# eglCreateFramebuffer() causes EGL_BAD_CONFIG (Invalid EGL frame buffer configuration)

Tags: egl, opengl-es-3.0

My app on Google Play is causing this error on customer devices (but not on my test devices, nor on Google's prelaunch report devices.)

**EGL_BAD_CONFIG** (Invalid EGL frame buffer configuration)

When doing this call: `eglCreateContext( display, config, NULL, contextAttribs );`

The attributes I pass:

```
const EGLint contextAttribs[] =
{
  EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3,
  EGL_NONE
};
```

The display is successfully retrieved like this:

```
EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay( EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY );
```

The config was successfully retrieved with: `eglChooseConfig()` using these attributes...

```
        const EGLint attribs[] = {
                EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, withDepthBuffer ? 16 : 0,
                EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_NONE
        };
```

...and these fallback attributes if none match:

```
        const EGLint attribs_fallback[] = {
                EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
                EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
                EGL_NONE
        };
```

After the `eglChooseConfig()` of preferred or fallback config, the numConfigs that matches is at least 1.

Also, the preceding call to `eglCreateWindowSurface()` succeeds as well.

This is with:

EGL **VENDOR**:Android

EGL **VERSION**:1.4 Android META-EGL

What is causing some devices to fail on the eglCreateContext() call?

And if it is invalid, why is eglChooseConfig returning the offending config?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is caused by the app getting launched by ES2-only devices, even though the manifest requires ES3 capability.

Answer (score 1):

Need more info. Query all the attributes of the config you are choosing - print out, see if something funny there.

I'm with Bram, you might be selecting a ES2 config and then requiring ES3 context.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely no longer relevant for you, but I had same problem and posting my fix here in case someone else also will encounter this problem in future:

Like stonesthrow said & you suspected config is ES2 and not ES3, causing incompatibility.
Changing `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` from `EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT` to `EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT` helped for me.